# ffmpeg input with comma sign and `amovie` filter

Tags: android, audio, video, ffmpeg, command

i'm adding audio to mute video using given command:

```
-i, input.mp4, 
-filter_complex, 
amovie=abc, xyz.mp3,asetpts=N/SR/TB,volume=0.0[a], 
-map, 0:v, 
-map, [a], 
-c:v, copy, 
-preset, ultrafast, 
-shortest, 
output.mp4
```

It works fine until `,` enters in input path as shown in above command and throws given error :

```
Error initializing filter 'amovie'

with args '/..folderPath../abc'
(while audio name was "abc, xyz.mp3")
```

How can i ignore comma separator in input path, any help will be appreciated,Thank you..

Comment: Why mix silent audio with the original audio?

Comment: No, It's originally mute video .So,actually I'm adding new Audio to mute video,please make me correct if I'm wrong anyhow.

Comment: I have updated my command in question,please check it out.